# Executing a function after the dgrid renderRow

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I'm trying to tie a function to be executed after the `renderRow` event of the grid. So I used the aspect.after from DOJO, but here is the kicker. This execute before the row is indeed rendered, therefore the divs\tds are not on the screen yet. And since I do want to use the position of the items, using the `dojo/domgeometry` returns an object filled with zeroes. How can I guarantee that my function will execute after the row is finished displaying?

Below you can find the JS where I'm calling it.

```
    aspect.after(grid, 'renderRow', function(row, args) {
        var object = args[0];
        if (object.type == 'tipo_exec') {
            row.className += ' black';
        } else if(object.type == 'exec') {
            row.className += ' gray';
        } else if(object.type == 'ic') {
            if ((typeof(object.dep)!='undefined') && (object.dep.length > 0)) {
                require(['dojo/dom-geometry','dojo/dom-construct'],
                    function(domGeom, domConstruct){
                        console.log(domGeom.position(row));
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        return row;
    });
```

EDIT: Another thing, I'm using the tree extension, and the renderRow happens after a click on the parent to expand.

EDIT: So here is a bit of more info in case it is needed. The store is simple:

```
    store = new Observable(new Memory({'data': data,
        'getChildren': function(parent, options){
            return this.query({'parent': parent.id}, options);
        },
        'mayHaveChildren': function(parent){
            return parent.hasChildren;
        }
    }));
```

And the grid is declared as:

```
grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, Keyboard, CompoundColumns]))({
        'columns': nCols,
        'query': { 'parent': undefined },
        'store': store

    }, gridId);
```

This is the inside of the aspect after

```
if ((typeof(object.dep)!='undefined') && (object.dep.length > 0)) {
    console.log('just before adding the refresh');
        on.once(this, 'dgrid-refresh-complete', function(){
            console.log('finished refreshing');
            require(['dojo/dom-geometry','dojo/dom-construct'],
                function(domGeom, domConstruct){
                    console.log(domGeom.position(node));
                }
            );
        });
}
```

The `console.log('finished refreshing');`never gets called, neither does the the position log.

There are many columns on the grid, a couple tied on a compouding column, a name colum which is a tree, and a couple of others. The renderRow is called when expanding the tree!

[Image of the grid with a couple of data removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nVWp.png)

Comment: @ahmed very bad idea.

Comment: setTimeout was suggested in a comment that has since been deleted.

Comment: It is, but problem is I think I will have to resort to it. Using a timeout that autorefreshes until the position returns non-zero data. It is clunky as hell, but better than nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can defer the invocation of `domGeom.position(row)` until the `dgrid-refresh-complete` event has been emitted. You'll need to include dojo/on.

```
aspect.after(grid, 'renderRow', function(row, args) {
    var object = args[0];
    if (object.type == 'tipo_exec') {
        row.className += ' black';
    } else if(object.type == 'exec') {
        row.className += ' gray';
    } else if(object.type == 'ic') {
        if ((typeof(object.dep)!='undefined') && (object.dep.length > 0)) {
            on.once(this, 'dgrid-refresh-complete', function(){
                require(['dojo/dom-geometry','dojo/dom-construct'],
                    function(domGeom, domConstruct){
                        console.log(domGeom.position(row));
                    }
                );
            })
        }
    }
    return row;
});
```

**EDIT**
Updated jsfiddle to accommodate tree
http://jsfiddle.net/rayotte/q8bCx/2/

Comment: Sweet, going to try it and will post the results here after

Comment: It does not work unfortunately. I tried both connecting the `dgrid-refresh-complete` event to the grid and the grid.domNode (as it is called on the onDemandList.js) but neither options get triggered. If it makes any difference, this is the declaration for the grid. 

`declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, Keyboard, CompoundColumns])`

Comment: The code has been tested and works. Maybe one of the conditions in `if ((typeof(object.dep)!='undefined') && (object.dep.length > 0))` isn't met.

Comment: No. I put a log before the on.once line and it got triggered. The domGeom console didn't. Did you make\test it using the tree extension on one of the columns?

Comment: I didn't use the tree plugin but before I try that, which version of dgrid and Dojo are you using? I'm asking because the `dgrid-refresh-complete` event was added in a later version. I'm currently on dgrid  0.3.11 and Dojo 1.9.1

Comment: Dojo 1.9.1 and dgrid 0.3.8 . I will update to 0.3.11 and see if it solves. Thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: So I just tested with your fiddle, update my dgrid to 0.3.11 and made a couple of tests on my code. The problem is that expanding a row when using the tree extension does not trigger the `dgrid-refresh-complete` event. If the row rendered normally, it does get called. You can check it on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yohanleafheart/q8bCx/1/ . I marked your answer as correct, because it is as long as you are not using the tree extension

Comment: I've made a modification to accommodate the tree case. Have a look and let me know if it does the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/rayotte/q8bCx/2/

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. Another possibility I found is hooking the function to the `transitionend` event, but that does not work on browsers who do not have the transition.

Comment: Great, I'll clean up the answer and will delete the comments once done to keep things tidy if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, go for it. Thanks a lot for the answer. That is one complicated thing done, now I have to focus on the other question I added.

Comment: You're welcome. I might be able to help with the other question too but it might not be for a couple of days. I'm a little backed up with work.

Comment: No worries mate, you have helped a lot. I've been trying to check the dgrid/dojo questions here, but since I'm starting on it, can't help that much. I will try though.